Join us in celebrating Pieter's amazing accomplishment!
Pieter Wuille recently reached a special reputation milestone on the Bitcoin StackExchange site!
Join me in congratulating Pieter on this accomplishment - he's the first person to reach 100,000 points.
Pieter - thanks for being so knowledgeable, friendly, and always willing to help - without you, and folks like you, this community just wouldn't be the same.


 ██████╗ ██████╗ ███╗   ██╗ ██████╗ ██████╗  █████╗ ████████╗███████╗
██╔════╝██╔═══██╗████╗  ██║██╔════╝ ██╔══██╗██╔══██╗╚══██╔══╝██╔════╝
██║     ██║   ██║██╔██╗ ██║██║  ███╗██████╔╝███████║   ██║   ███████╗
██║     ██║   ██║██║╚██╗██║██║   ██║██╔══██╗██╔══██║   ██║   ╚════██║
╚██████╗╚██████╔╝██║ ╚████║╚██████╔╝██║  ██║██║  ██║   ██║   ███████║
 ╚═════╝ ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═══╝ ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝   ╚══════╝
                                                                     
 ██████╗ ███╗   ██╗     ██╗ ██████╗  ██████╗ ██╗  ██╗                
██╔═══██╗████╗  ██║    ███║██╔═████╗██╔═████╗██║ ██╔╝                
██║   ██║██╔██╗ ██║    ╚██║██║██╔██║██║██╔██║█████╔╝                 
██║   ██║██║╚██╗██║     ██║████╔╝██║████╔╝██║██╔═██╗                 
╚██████╔╝██║ ╚████║     ██║╚██████╔╝╚██████╔╝██║  ██╗                
 ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═══╝     ╚═╝ ╚═════╝  ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝                
                                                                     
██████╗ ██╗███████╗████████╗███████╗██████╗ ██╗                      
██╔══██╗██║██╔════╝╚══██╔══╝██╔════╝██╔══██╗██║                      
██████╔╝██║█████╗     ██║   █████╗  ██████╔╝██║                      
██╔═══╝ ██║██╔══╝     ██║   ██╔══╝  ██╔══██╗╚═╝                      
██║     ██║███████╗   ██║   ███████╗██║  ██║██╗                      
╚═╝     ╚═╝╚══════╝   ╚═╝   ╚══════╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝                      




Yay, congratulations @PieterWuille

SInce I am addicted to worthless internet points, I too congratulate Pieter on this milestone. More than that, it is an opportunity to thank him for all the carefully thought out and well written answers, invariably with helpful & friendly tone, that Pieter has contributed here over many years.

Thanks all! It's been a pleasure so far.

In last two years I've asked over 50 questions on the Bitcoin.SE and you answered many of them. I learned a lot from your responses, whether answers or comments. Thanks a lot.

You deserve this credit absolutely, thank you for answering even the stupidest of questions in the most intelligent ways.

Never cease to be amazed by PW. Patient, thorough, great breadth of knowledge, posts everywhere, amazing amount of output. What a star.
